# How to time functions with timeit and save results

Tags: python-3.x, timeit

I'm trying to compare the speed of my functions using `timeit` but saving the results of these and I can't achieve that. Let me show you a toy example, trying to compare diferent matrix multiplication functions:

```
from timeit import timeit
import numpy as np

def prod_tensorial (A,B)  : return np.tensordot(A,B,(-1,0))
def prod_punto (A,B)      : return np.dot(A,B)
def prod_sumeinsten (A,B) : return np.einsum('ij,jk->ik',A,B)

A = np.random.rand(1000,2000)
B = np.random.rand(2000,3000)

fs = ( prod_tensorial, prod_punto, prod_sumeinsten )
ts = [ ]
ps = [ ]

for f in fs:
    ts += [ timeit('ps += [f(A,B)]',number=1) ]     # error: ps & f didn't recognized
    #ts += [ timeit(lambda: f(A,B),number=1) ]      # it works but lossing results
    print( ts[-1] )

print(np.allclose(*ps))
```

How you can see, I can't save the results. Do you know how could I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Function `timeit` does not have direct access to the global variables. You must provide the dictionary of the global variabes through the `globals` keyword. Since the variable `ps` is first *read* in the timed statement, it is by default considered local. Mark it as global:

```
# This part is only for testing
ps = []
def f(x,y): return x+y
A, B = 10, 11

timeit('global ps; ps += [f(A,B)]', number=1, globals=globals())
```

Comment: I'm still getting the same error. Could you check it please? https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1GbeT8k2gGIwawW3vmu2opbX10bYrLeMN?usp=sharing

Comment: Thanks a lot @DYZ! Just to leave all solved here, I add the complete line for my example: `ts += [ timeit('global ps,f; ps += [f(A,B)]', number=1, globals=globals()) ]`

Comment: `f` is already global, there is no need to mark it. But whatever.

Comment: You are right, it's enough declaring ds as global. Thanks again! `ts += [ timeit('global ps; ps += [f(A,B)]', number=1, globals=globals()) ]`

Comment: Please, one question else: I always have to declare as global just the first variable which I use inside the script?

Comment: Please read about local, nonlocal, and global variables in Python. There are many tutorials. It's not a single-phrase question.

Comment: I have just readed about that. It's because `ps` is being assiged inside the script, just like a function. Otherwise, it would be enough adding the `globals=globals()` parameter.